# Best way to pass threadId in log4j2 AsyncLogger

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, log4j, log4j2

I would like to log the thread Id as part of my log message using `log4j2` Async logging.

With `log4j2` 2.4.1 this was possible via a custom `AsyncLogger` which overwrites the logMessage method.

```
public class ThreadIdAsyncLogger extends AsyncLogger {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final ThreadLocal<Boolean> THREAD_CONTEXT_SETUP = new ThreadLocal<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean initialValue() {
            return false;
        }
    };

    public ThreadIdAsyncLogger(final LoggerContext context, final String name, final MessageFactory messageFactory) {
        super(context, name, messageFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void logMessage(final String fqcn,
                           final Level level,
                           final Marker marker,
                           final Message message,
                           final Throwable thrown) {
        if (!THREAD_CONTEXT_SETUP.get()) {
            // it is enough to set it once per thread
            ThreadContext.put(Constants.ContextMapKeys.THREAD_ID, String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()));
            THREAD_CONTEXT_SETUP.set(true);
        }

        super.logMessage(fqcn, level, marker, message, thrown);
    }
}
```

I just tried to update to version 2.5.0 and now I dont seem to be able to create my own `AsyncLogger` anymore because the `AsyncLoggerDisruptor` is package private.
I know i could use reflection but I guess there is a better way for this.

What would be the best practice (desing and performance wise) for achieving the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is work in progress for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1270

Meanwhile you can use the ThreadLocal map or stack methods to accomplish this. Performance-wise the ThreadLocal stack is slightly cheaper than the map I think.

Comment: at which place in the code should i push the threadId on the stack? I would like to do this in once place in the logger and not before every logger call in app code. What do you suggest here? should I wait (stay at 2.4.1) until the ticket you mentioned is resovled?

Comment: There is usually a single entry point where your application receives a callback from the framework that provides the threading model. If your application is some tasks in a thread pool, that would be the Runnable's run() method or the Callable's call() method. For Servlets it is one of the service() or doXxx() methods. Other frameworks have other callbacks, but in general those entry points would be the ideal candidate to push the thread ID (and pop it after your code is done).

Comment: ok i understand. unfortunately i can only do this for the code i control and not for some "middleware" threads. looking at the log4j async logger code, i see you already need to obtain the threadid anyway maybe it would be possible to pass it along with the LogEvent if you anyway have it. i will think about some solution ..

Comment: hm, looking again at the code of AsyncLogger and RingBufferLogEventTranslator it looks like the threadId should already be on the LogEvent if I am using not cached thread name strategy @ AsyncLogger#initTranslatorThreadValues

Comment: You're looking at the master branch in GitHub? That will be released in the upcoming version 2.6.

Comment: yes exactly, i am looking at master on github, looks very nice. do you (roughly) know when 2.6 will be released?

Comment: I'd say at least a few weeks. Depends on the progress of this epic: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1270